# django class based views post method not reading from other methods

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am running a classed based view on django. It's very strange that my post method does not take on other methods in the class.

My get_context_data works and could take in and print self.get_msg(), however, my post method when I run it, it takes me to a page not found 404 page, because of the self.get_msg() function that I included inside the post function. I need the post function to take in some parameters so I could save it in the model.

Does anyone know why that might be the case and how do I get around it? Any advice would be welcome.

Thank you

```
class OpeningConfirmApp(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'opening/opening_confirm_app.html'
    form_class = PriceForm

    def get_msg(self, *args, **kwargs):
        msg_id = self.request.GET.get("msg_id")
        msg = get_object_or_404(Message, pk=msg_id)
        parent_msg_id = msg.parent_id
        msg = get_object_or_404(Message, pk=parent_msg_id)
        return msg

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(OpeningConfirmApp, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        #working
        print self.get_msg()

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        #not working
        print self.get_msg()

        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            price = form.cleaned_data.get("price")
            return self.form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        msg = self.get_msg()
        messages.success(self.request, "Your application has been sent.")
        return reverse('MessageDetail', kwargs={'pk': msg.id})
```

below is my html if that helps.

```
<br>
<form action="{% url 'OpeningConfirmApp' %}" method="get" style="display: inline">
<input type="hidden" name="msg_id" value="{{object.id}}">
<input class='btn btn-success' type="submit" value="Apply for Opening">
</form>
<br>
```

Comment: Add `print(msg_id)` in your `get_msg` method. Are you sure it's the value you expect it to be?

Comment: I just tested you code locally to my PC and the `self.get_msg()` is called.

Comment: If it's taking you to a 404 page, then it *is* being called. Why do you think it isn't? You're clearly hitting the `get_object_or_404` in that method.

Comment: Yes It is being called, but I don't understand why the print self.get_msg works when called on the get_context_data but not in the post method which is strange.

Comment: If I am docked a point for asking this I hope someone lets me know why I am docked. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after researching hints bruno desthuilliers gave. This solution requires me to do another url and function. The new function redirects to my main function to do the posting.

I have to add another url.py to collect the msg_id which is based on the pk in the first url.

```
url(r'^messagedetail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/appoffconf$', AppOffConf, name='AppOffConf'),
```

and add another function to view.py to record the session and then redirect that to my main function.

```
def AppOffConf(request, pk):
    request.session["msg_id"] = pk
    return redirect("OpeningConfirmApp")
```

This way it can retrieve the msg_id without requiring both post and get (which would complicate my submission and wobbily_col mentioned the request.REQUEST method to access both GET and POST dictionaries has been removed in 1.10 which is what I am using) My main function to do the post will therefore be changed to self.request.session.get("msg_id") instead of self.request.GET.get("msg_id")

```
class OpeningConfirmApp(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'opening/opening_confirm_app.html'
    form_class = PriceForm

    def get_msg(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #changed from - msg_id = self.request.GET.get("msg_id")
        msg_id = self.request.session.get("msg_id")
        msg = get_object_or_404(Message, pk=msg_id)
        parent_msg_id = msg.parent_id
        msg = get_object_or_404(Message, pk=parent_msg_id)
        return msg

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(OpeningConfirmApp, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        #working
        print self.get_msg()

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        #working now
        print self.get_msg()

        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            price = form.cleaned_data.get("price")
            return self.form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        msg = self.get_msg()
        messages.success(self.request, "Your application has been sent.")
        return reverse('MessageDetail', kwargs={'pk': msg.id})
```

The html is changed to direct the form button to the first url/function and from there it will be redirected to my main function to do posting.

```
<form action='appoffconf' method="post" style="display: inline">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="msg_id" value="{{i.id}}">
<input class='btn btn-success buttonspace' type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
```

Comment: Checking both `request.GET` and `request.POST` wouldn't have been _that_ difficult either - `msg_id = request.GET.get('msg_id', request.POST.get('msg_id', None))`

Answer (score 1):

Your `get_msg()` method tries to get `msg_id` from `request.GET`. This key won't be set in a POST request, so `msg_id` will be `None`, so `get_object_or_404` will raise.

The canonical solution here is to pass "msg_id" as part of the url instead of as a GET param. Your url regexp would then looks something like

```
 r"/msg/something/(?P<msg_id>\d+)/$",
```

and you'd get "msg_id" in your view's kwargs whatever the request method.

If you really have to have it as request param, then you need to pass it back to the form that actually posts to your view (you only showed a form that does a GET request here).

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want your form to have a post method instead of a get?

```
<form action="{% url 'OpeningConfirmApp' %}" method="POST" style="display: inline">
```

Otherwise it won't get to your POST method at all. (That's probably why you don't see the print statement from the post method).

And as Bruno says, your get_msg method is taking data from the request.GET rather than request.POST, so you will need to check both. (Django used to offer a request.REQUEST method to access both GET and POST dictionaries, but I see it has been removed as of 1.10.)